# Prove that the Sturm's functions are divisible by the $gcd(f(x),f_1(x))$.

Tags: polynomials, proof-explanation, systems-of-equations

I was studying about Sturm's functions. The thing given as the definition of Sturm's function(or an explanation for Sturm's functions) is:

> Let $f(x)$ be a polynomial with real coefficients and $f_1(x)$ be its first derivative .Let the operation of finding the h.c.f of $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ be performed with the following modification.*The sign of each remainder is to be changed before it is used as the
> next divisor and the sign of the last remainder is also to be changed*.The modified remainders(i.e.,the remainders with their signs changed) are denoted by $f_2(x),f_3(x),...,f_r(x)$.$f(x),f_1(x),...,f_r(x)$ are called Sturm's functions and $f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_r(x)$ are called auxiliary functions.In the usual process of finding the h.c.f. of two polynomials we can multiply (or divide) any remainder by a constant, positive or negative
> but in this modified process of forming Sturm's auxiliary functions it is essential that such multipliers should be positive.If $q_1(x),q_2(x),...,q_{r-1}(x)$ be the quotients in the successive steps,the Sturm's functions $f(x),f_1(x),f_2(x),...,f_r(x)$ are connected by the equations:$f=q_1f_1-f_2,f_1=q_2f_2-f_3,...,f_{r-1}=q_{r-1}f_{r-1}-f_r.$ It is to be observed that  the last remainder $-f_r(x)$ is a constant if $f(x)$ has no multiple root. But if $f(x)$ has multiple roots then the h.c.f. of $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ is a polynomial,say $p(x).$In this case all the Sturm's functions are divisible by $p(x)$ and the remainder $-f_r(x)=p(x)\phi_r(x)$,where $\phi_r(x)$ is a constant.

I do not get what they mean by this line :*In the usual process of finding the h.c.f. of two polynomials we can
multiply (or divide) any remainder by a constant, positive or negative
but in this modified process of forming Sturm's auxiliary functions it is essential that such multipliers should be positive*.Also, how are they concluding the fact that "It is to be observed that  the last remainder $-f_r(x)$ is a constant if $f(x)$ has no multiple root"? I don't get how they say:"But if $f(x)$ has multiple roots then the h.c.f. of $f(x)$ and $f_1(x)$ is a polynomial, say $p(x).$ In this case all the Sturm's functions are divisible by $p(x)$ and the remainder $-f_r(x)=p(x)\phi_r(x)$,where $\phi_r(x)$ is a constant" ?

Comment: Should I provide more context?...If so, where are the portions which needs more clarity?...